# Angular Material 2: None of the modules are recognised in Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-material2

I am trying to setup the Angular Material 2 in a Angular CLI project. I'm using the last versions. I added the references in the module and component file but when I try to used it noting is working.
I followed all the steps from the setup instructions from the documentation but still not working. And I have no errors.

I can give you an example for the Datepicker component.

```
import { MdDatepickerModule, MdNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
.
.
.
exports: [
   ...
    MdDatepickerModule,
    MdNativeDateModule,
   ...
  ],
  imports: [
   ...
    MdDatepickerModule,
    MdNativeDateModule,
   ...
]
```

Here is my main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'; 
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) { 
  enableProdMode();
}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: Share your main.ts file

Comment: More importantly, share you error log !

Comment: Hello, Here is my main.ts<br/>
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';<br/>

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';<br/>


import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';<br/>

import { environment } from './environments/environment';<br/>



if (environment.production) {<br/>
  enableProdMode();<br/>
}<br/>

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

Comment: Have you installed `@angular/animations` and imported `BrowserAnimationsModule`? Can't locate it in your code.

Comment: Yes. I installed @angular/animations and BrowserAnimationsModule is in the module. Sorry my bad I didn't put this in the example. But in my project is there.

Comment: Are you using Angular 2 or Angular 4?

Comment: Problem solved. Was a problem with the versioning of the packages